# Biblatex and addbibresource not displayed

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem with citing and displaying the correct `.bib` content when using `\printbibliography`. I have the following

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,bibstyle=ieee,sorting=none]            
{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}


\addbibresource{mendeley.bib}
```

While my `.bib` file looks like this.

```
@techreport{Ottersland2018RosteeReport,
title = {{Rostee Preliminary Report}},
year = {2018},
author = {Ottersland, Martin},
pages = {19},
url = {https://something/otherthing/lastthing/someindex.extension},
institution = {University of Agder},
address = {Grimstad}
```

I call `\printbibliography[title={Sources}]` to print my sources with a new title name, there are no `\cite`s in the document, so sources should print blank. But instead the printed result looks like this:

```
Sources
[1]I. G. 2012. (2012). Section of cancer surveillance, [Online]. 
Available:http : / /globocan.iarc.fr/Pages/fact_sheets_cancer.aspx.
```

First of this reference does not exist in my `.bib`, and I do not know why it is there. What am I doing wrong? The path and name for the `.bib` file is in order, as well as the import....

Comment: That's strange. There is probably something in your settings you are not considering. I'll suggest you try to produce a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/
[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that reproduces the issue. Likely, you will figure out in the process what the problem is. If not, we will stand a better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Try deleting all the auxiliary files (`.bbl`, `.aux`, ...) and recompile.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That solved everything, you should post it as a solution so i can give you a vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\printbibliography` will print the information available in the `.bbl` file, which is generated by `biber`. What you describe indicates that you have an old `.bbl` file lying around, from a time when your document did have a citation.

So to fix it, do one of two things:

1. Delete the `.bbl` file.
2. Re-run `biber`, so the `bbl` file is rewritten.